# MAMP does not start

Tags: php, mysql, webserver

Hello everyone I saw an old discussion which has the same problem as me.
MAMP won't start at all. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling MAMP, but the newly installed version won't start either.
I'm on a MacBook Pro running high Sierra.

How I can get it working again? Thanks

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I tried to open MAMP by clicking on it and it doesn't even open..

Comment: Try adding more details, and it would be better if you link the old problem discussion link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786196/mamp-will-not-start

that's the old link